# VTK 8.1.1 & Qt QML: Dual Depth Peeling not working

Tags: c++, qt, qml, vtk

The application I'm working on is based on Qt QML and I'm frequently using  VTK via the vtkExternalOpenGLRenderWindow rendering to a QQuickFramebufferObject. Because semi-transparent geometries weren't rendered correctly I found out about the dual depth peeling and enabled it as recommended on the VTK website:

https://www.vtk.org/Wiki/VTK/Examples/Cxx/Visualization/CorrectlyRenderTranslucentGeometry

```
   _renderer = vtkSmartPointer<vtkRenderer>::New();
   _renderer->SetUseDepthPeeling( 1 );
   _renderer->SetMaximumNumberOfPeels( 100 );
   _renderer->SetOcclusionRatio( 0.1 );
   _renderWindow = vtkExternalOpenGLRenderWindow::New();
   _renderWindow->SetAlphaBitPlanes( 1 );
   _renderWindow->SetMultiSamples( 0 );
   _renderWindow->AddRenderer( _renderer );
```

Unfortunately all I can see now is a red background. (Note: Red isn't a color I'm using for any objects or backgrounds)

The Versions I'm using are VTK Version 8.1.1 and Qt 5.11.2

Has anyone tried something similar with vtkExternalOpenGLRenderWindow, QQuickFramebufferObject and Dual Depth Peeling? Or an idea what might be the problem.

Comment: It might be that your box doesn't support depth peeling? ["Depth peeling requires a variety of openGL extensions and appropriate drivers"](https://www.vtk.org/Wiki/VTK/Examples/Cxx/Visualization/CorrectlyRenderTranslucentGeometry).  Does that example work on your box?

Comment: According to the printout in the terminal depth peeling is supported it says: "DEPTH PEELING SUPPORT: YES". But then I get the following error and no rendering is displayed **vtkOpenGLRenderer (0x7fb9a4f1bb30): failed after Clear 1 OpenGL errors detected
  0 : (1286) Invalid framebuffer operation**

Comment: [This gamedev article](https://www.gamedev.net/forums/topic/608990-invalid-framebuffer-operation/) suggests maybe your frame buffer is not complete at the time of the clear.  Your graphics card driver might be at the route of the problem - get the latest and greatest driver for your GPU and try again?  Or try on a different machine?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you have the same problem but I'm also using VTK via the `vtkExternalOpenGLRenderWindow` rendering to a `QQuickFramebufferObject` and I had problems with transparency. I tried to enabled depth peeling support too but it did not work. For me it was all black (not red). Anyway I ended up not enabling depth peeling and I did the following instead.

You must have created a class Renderer inheriting from `QQuickFramebufferObject::Renderer`. This class creates a framebuffer object. Note that by default, the FBO is created without any attachment, which means that the OpenGL depth and stencil tests won't work when rendering to a framebuffer object without any depth or stencil buffers (transparent objects will not be rendered correctly). But you can customize the creation of this framebuffer by overriding `createFramebufferObject`:

```
QOpenGLFramebufferObject * createFramebufferObject( const QSize & p_size ) override
{
    // If the GL_EXT_packed_depth_stencil extension is present, a combined depth and stencil buffer is attached.
    // If the extension is not present, only a depth buffer is attached.
    QOpenGLFramebufferObjectFormat format;
    format.setAttachment( QOpenGLFramebufferObject::CombinedDepthStencil );
    return new QOpenGLFramebufferObject( p_size, format );
}
```

Doing that fixed my transparency problems. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for the hint. Unfortunately I'm already creating the FBO in the same way.